# Excel closes when I close the main window in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, excel, user-controls

I have a Excel AddIn project which parses excel workbook and pops a wpf window from excel ribbon when clicked on a button. the problem is that when I close the window (UI control of type window)pop up. closing action on Window closes the Excel too.

the code is something like this to show the window.

```
MainWindow main= new MainWindow();
main.ShowDialog();
```

can someone tell what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have to question why you are creating a new instance of MainWindow?

What you should be doing is (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx):

```
// Instantiate window
DialogBox dialogBox = new DialogBox();

// Show window modally 
// NOTE: Returns only when window is closed
Nullable<bool> dialogResult = dialogBox.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: even in your case, you are instantiating the dialogbox? aren't you?

Comment: Indeed, a dialog box, not a main window. Give it a shot, it may solve your problem. ;)

Comment: I am not sure if I am able to follow you. MainWindow is a UI control of type window in my application. how can both be related (DialogBox and Window in this case). I want to open the mainwindow when user clicks a button on ribbon in EXCEL. hence I was calling on button click even Mainwindow.ShowDialog().

Comment: Ahh, yeah this wont help (my answer would have caused mass confusion for you). You may want to update the question with that info. I figured you were opening an excel doc in your program, and was trying to call a new instance of the main window just to display a dialog box. Which in turn was closing your excel doc before you were finished processing. Yes, we all know what happens when someone assumes... XD